# Reading lots of files using producer causes CPU usage to be 100%

Tags: java, multithreading, file, cpu-usage, producer-consumer

I wrote a simple consumer-producer pattern to help me achieve the following task:

1. Read a file from a directory that contain ~500,000 TSV (tab-separated) files.
2. Manipulate each file into a data structure and put it in blocking queue.
3. Consume the queue using consumer and query DB.
4. Compare both hash-maps and if there's a difference, print difference to file.

When I run the program, even with 5 threads, my CPU consumption skyrockets to 100%. Could this be because I'm using a single producer to read the files?

**File example (tab separated)**

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column 4   Column5
A         1         *         -          -
B         1         *         -          -
C         1         %         -          -
```

**Producer**

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
private BlockingQueue<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> m_Queue;
private String m_Directory;

public Producer(BlockingQueue<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> i_Queue, String i_Directory)
{
    m_Queue = i_Queue;
    m_Directory = i_Directory;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    if (Files.exists(Paths.get(m_Directory)))
    {
        File[] files = new File(m_Directory).listFiles();

        if (files != null)
        {
            for (File file : files)
            {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
                {
                    String line, lastcolumn3 = "", column1 = "", column2 = "", column3 = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //Skip column header
                        if (!Character.isLetter(line.charAt(0)))
                        {
                            String[] splitLine = line.split("\t");

                            column1 = splitLine[0].replace("\"", "");
                            column2 = splitLine[1].replace("\"", "");
                            column3 = splitLine[2].replace("\"", "");

                            if (!lastcolumn3.equals(column3))
                            {
                                map.put(column3, column1);
                                lastcolumn3 = column3;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    map.put(column3, column1);

                    //Column 1 is always the same per file, it'll be the key. Column2 and Column3 are stored as the value (as a key-value pair)
                    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapPerFile = new HashMap<>();
                    mapPerFile.put(column2, map);

                    m_Queue.put(mapPerFile);
                }
                catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(file);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

**Consumer**

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{
private HashMap<String, String> m_DBResults;
private BlockingQueue<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> m_Queue;
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> m_DBResultsPerFile;
private String m_Column1;
private int m_ThreadID;

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> i_Queue, int i_ThreadID)
{
    m_Queue = i_Queue;
    m_ThreadID = i_ThreadID;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while ((m_DBResultsPerFile = m_Queue.poll()) != null)
        {
            //Column1 is always the same, only need the first entry.
            m_Column1 = m_DBResultsPerFile.keySet().toArray()[0].toString();

            //Queries DB and puts returned data into m_DBResults
            queryDB(m_Column1);

            //Write the difference, if any, per thread into a file.
            writeDifference();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeDifference()
{
    MapDifference<String, String> difference = Maps.difference(m_DBResultsPerFile.get(m_Column1), m_DBResults);

    if (difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().size() > 0 || difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().size() > 0)
    {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(String.format("thread_%d.tsv", m_ThreadID), true)))
        {
            if (difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().size() > 0)
            {
                writer.write(String.format("%s\t%s\t", "Missing", m_Column1));
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().entrySet())
                {
                    writer.write(String.format("[%s,%s]; ", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }

                writer.write("\n");
            }
            if (difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().size() > 0)
            {
                writer.write(String.format("%s\t%s\t", "Extra", m_Column1));
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().entrySet())
                {
                    writer.write(String.format("[%s,%s]; ", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }

                writer.write("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
BlockingQueue<Map<String, Map<String,String>>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue <> ();

//Start the reader thread.
threadPool.execute(new Producer(queue, args[0]));

//Create configurable threads.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threadPool.execute(new Consumer(queue, i + 1));
}

threadPool.shutdown();
System.out.println("INFO: Shutting down threads.");

try {
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    System.out.println("INFO: Threadpool terminated successfully.");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: Is CPU utilisation a bad thing?

Comment: Would you prefer your work get done more slowly?

Comment: If you believe you're using more CPU than you should (i.e. total run time is too high), perhaps your algorithm is bad. Profile the code to see where problem might be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Of course not, but is 100% seems right?

Comment: @Andreas I think that 100% CPU is not good no matter the case.

Comment: How many cores does the machine have?

Comment: If 100% CPU is bad, what level of CPU is good, and why? Or asked the other way, why should program slow down to reduce CPU load, and just let CPU sit idle, instead of using it? It's like giving a carrot to a hungry man, but telling him to only eat half and throw the rest out. Waste of resources.

Answer (score 6):

Your CPU usage is most likely due to this:

```
while ((m_DBResultsPerFile = m_Queue.poll()) != null)
```

The `poll` method does not block.  It returns immediately.  So you're executing that loop millions of times per second.

You should be using `take()`, which actually waits until an element becomes available:

```
while ((m_DBResultsPerFile = m_Queue.take()) != null)
```

The [documentation for BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) nicely summarizes all of this, in a way that (in my opinion) eliminates any confusion.

Comment: `take()` won't actually ever return `null`.

Comment: I tried to replace poll() with take() and didn't see much of a difference. I'll see if I can better tweak the producer class.